# Complication with clustree image generation

Tags: r, bioinformatics, resolution, hierarchical-clustering, rna-seq

Running the below code (initially without par (lwd = 1) line ) returned the following error, and the same error was returned again after setting par(lwd = 1) or to 0.5 or 10. Truthfully don't totally understand what's going on when i change that variable other than that id be changing the width of the lines of the plot?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to R and trying to perform some of my own scRNA analyses but would like to use clustree to visualize and determine # of clusters in my dataset. Until this work I will just mess around with my resolution in Seurat and find something that seems reasonable - but would prefer this approach and want to understand what I'm doing wrong for the future. Thanks for any help!!

```
#Use clustree to determine best resolution for this dataset 
library(clustree)
CD4_PI_clust <- FindClusters(CD4_g_PI, resolution = c(0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1))

par(lwd = 1)
det_clus_num <- clustree(x = CD4_PI_clust@meta.data, prefix = "RNA_snn_res.")
det_clus_num
```

explained above !

Comment: CD45_tumor_biopsy <- FindClusters(CD45_tumor_biopsy, resolution = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0))
par(lwd = 1)
plot_clustree <- clustree(CD45_tumor_biopsy@meta.data, prefix = "RNA_snn_res.")
plot_clustree

Followed your code, which i believe was identical to my own? but still receiving same error. new to stack so not sure why my code is being written without line by line notation/format but in my script i am writing line by line. same error

> plot_clustree
Error in check.length(gparname) : 
  'gpar' element 'lwd' must not be length 0

even after setting par(lwd = 1)